# Delete script only deleting files not folders

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, delete-directory

I have a script that I run every week via a cron that delete loads of temp files on my web servers but I've just notice that the script is not removing the folders which are still taking up space.

Whats the best to amend the script to delete the folders as well?

```
find /my/path/ -type d –ctime +5 –exec rm -r {} \;

#!/bin/bash
# Deletes temp files older then 5 days
DOCS='/var/www/user/docs/temp'
SCRATCH='/var/www/user/temp/scratch'

if [ -d "$DOCS" ]; then
find $DOCSJS -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \; > /tmp/docs.txt
fi
if [ -d "$SCRATCH" ]; then
find $SCRATCH -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \; > /tmp/docs.txt
fi
```

My script actually has -rf as a flag to delete all folders.

One point to note is that the folders aboves are symbolic links to `/mnt/sdb1/docs/js` and `/mnt/sdb1/temp/scratch` - would the script follow the symbolic link or should I hard code this to the mount?

Comment: to delete folders use `rm -rf` Plain `rm` do not delete folders

Comment: Sorry I amended the question as I already have that flag in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
if [ -d "$SCRATCH" ]; then
find $SCRATCH -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \; > /tmp/docs.txt
fi
```

into

```
if [ -d "$SCRATCH" ]; then
find $SCRATCH -type d -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \; > /tmp/docs.txt
fi
```

you only search for files using the `-type f` flag; use `-type d` for directories

Comment: ahhh of course - would that skip over files in the root of the folder -so should have have another two if statements just for files?

Comment: just skip the if-cases as well as `-type [fd]` and just use find with rm -rf

Comment: Thanks _ i'm removing the -type from the script

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass additional options to `rm` commands in your scripts. Actually you need `rm -rf`. At all I'd recommend to go `man 1 rm`.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
find $DOCSJS -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm
```

to:

```
find $DOCSJS -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm -Rf
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot delete directories as the output of `find` is limited to files. You should drop this option so that both old files and directories are passed to `rm -rf`

```
find $DIR -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This will preserve old directories which have new files in them (but it will remove the old files), but get rid of files and directories where both are old.